# Replace First Two Characters of XML Tag Value Match with Static Value

Tags: regex, xml, sed, grep, kml

I am trying to replace the first two characters of an XML tag `<LineStyle><color>` value match with `00` if the pattern match isn't `00`.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ff969696</color>
  </LineStyle>
    <color>ff969696</color>
  <LineStyle>
    <color>e680e680</color>
  </LineStyle>
    <color>e680e680</color>
  <LineStyle>
    <color>e680f7f7</color>
  </LineStyle>
    <color>e680f7f7</color>
  <LineStyle>
    <color>e67c88f4</color>
  </LineStyle>
    <color>e67c88f4</color>
```

Ex., a pattern match of `<LineStyle><color>ff......` or `<LineStyle><color>e6......` would be replaced with `<LineStyle><color>00......` and so on.

**Attempted Code**

```
sed 's/<LineStyle><color>[0-9][a-z]*/<LineStyle><color>00*/g'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -i.bak -0777 -pe 's{( <LineStyle> \s* <color> ) .. }{${1}00}gxms' in_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`.
`-0777` : Slurp files whole.

The regex uses these modifiers:
`/g` : Match the pattern repeatedly.
`/x` : Ignore whitespace and comments, for readability.
`/m` : Allow multiline matches.
`/s` : Allow `.` to match a newline.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Comment: THANK YOU Timur! This was precisely the solution that I was looking for. Thank you very much for your expertise!